# VHDL Editor with lint and intellisense

Tags: vhdl, development-tools

Is there a freeware VHDL editor out there that supports intellisense and lint? There are plenty for other programming languages but seems like none for HDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the question due to my reputation being under 50 however have you looked at these other questions?

- [Free IDE for VHDL and Verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24184/free-ide-for-vhdl-and-verilog)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768492/verilog-program-editor-and-compiler
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873536/professional-vhdl-ide

Even doing a quick Google search will bring up various editors/IDEs
E.g,

- https://github.com/rochus-keller/VerilogCreator
- http://www.vhdleditor.com/free

Or perhaps you could use a plugin to expand existing IDEs:

- https://atom.io/packages/ide-vhdl
- http://www.vide-software.at/ (For Visual Studio - it's free for 1 month or 6 if you are a student, if not, it's 30Eur for 12 months - not exactly free but it depends how long you are planning to use the IDE for, it's a one time thing then I imagine this would be suitable)

I'm sure if you look at the suggested IDEs/editors from the questions mentioned that you'll find one that meets your requirements.
Also it might be worth editing your question to include what operating system you are using.

Comment: I am using V3S (From VIDE-Software) and it is quite good. It has linting and many snippets. But Visual Studio itself is a mess...!
I also use Pu Zhao's VHDL plugin for VSCode and it is also quite a good plugin. Doesn't offer linting but it still offers basic error checking (mainly begin and end errors) and also some snippets which are really useful. VSCode is much easier to use.

Comment: I installed Pu Zhao's extension as well but I'm missing the linting as you mentioned. To bad the project is not alive anymore (at least doesn't seem to be).